# Возможно ли хранить сериализованный объект объект as3 на сервере ?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Поняв что такое json, мне хочется его с чем-то сравнить и на ум приходит лишь сериализованный объект. Но меня давно мучает вопрос, который пора уже задать - возможно ли хранить сериализованный объект в каком-то файле на сервере. Если да, то в каком расширении файла лучше хранить.

***Дополнение:***

[[@ShockWave](/users/1516/shockwave)](/users/1516/shockwave): Спасибо Вам огромное! Но у меня ещё несколько вопросов - я опять вижу строки:) что заставляет спросить - возможно ли в as3 сериализовать объект в бинарный массив и уже его передать на сервер и записать во что-то? То есть, если объект сериализовывать в xml, то насколько я знаю, это очень плохо особенно для мобильных устройств ( много памяти отъедает ), json будет предпочтительней, но как выяснилось, он так же как и xml строка, значение которой потом нужно приводить к типам ( я о простых типах ). Сам не когда не делал, но слышал, что объекты можно сериализовывать в бинарные форматы, которые быстрее передаются по сети и при десериализации сохраняют типы свойств да и вообще сам объект можно привести к определенному типу. И про бинарную сериализацию хочется узнать следующее - возможно ли бинарный массив сохранить на сервере, намного ли он быстрее передается по сети ( по сравнению с xml ) и делали Вы или возможно где-то читали о сравнении скорости десериалиазации бинарных данных по сравнению со скоростью приведения строки json к объекту и приведение типов этого объекта при помощи второго необязательного параметра метода parse? 
*текст курсивом*

Comment: - вроде AMF и RTMP, из бинарных протоколов передачи, но я с ним не сталкивался (http://www.fluorinefx.com/)
- естественно бинарник быстрей передается, и ресурсов меньше кушает
- как хранить на сервере такие данные не в курсе, вроде все опять парсится и в базу
- встречал минимум еще два формата, может позже чего нагуглю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хранить можно, например в базе для этого нужно:

- из объекта соорудить запрос SQL, содержащий поля этого объекта, сериализировать

вот примерный способ:

```
    var serialized:String = "UPDATE  `cards` SET 
       `apartment` = '+roomCombo.selectedIndex+
       `first_name` =  '+fName.text+
       `second_name` =  '+sName.text+
       `third_name` =  '+tName.text'+
       `date_in` =  '+dateIn.text+' 00:00:00'+
       `date_out` =  '+dateOut.text+' 00:00:00'+
       `sex` =  '+sexCombo.selectedIndex';
```

В обратном случае, при получении объекта с сервера, строим из результата запроса, строку, и уже во флеш приложении конвертим её в свой объект.

```
 var cardModel:XML = new XML("<item>"+
              "<apartment>1</apartment>"+
              "<first_name>*</first_name>"+
              "<second_name>*</second_name>"+
              "<third_name>*</third_name>"+
              "<date_in>2014-04-06 00:00:00</date_in>"+
              "<date_out>2014-04-06 00:00:00</date_out>"+
              "<sex>0</sex>"+
 "</item>");
```

На сервере таким может легко заниматься PHP:

следующий пример принимает запросы на сохранение в базу (CREATE, UPDATE), и отправляет объекты клиенту (SELECT FROM)

```
 <?php
  mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '1');
  mysql_select_db('booking');
  $sql = $_POST["sql"];
  if ( $sql == null ) $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `cards`';

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  if ( is_bool($result) ) die($result);

  echo "<data>\n";
  while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<item>\n";
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        echo "<$key>$value</$key>\n";
    }
    echo "</item>\n";
  }
  echo "</data>";
?>
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте AMF. Он нативный для Flash и компактный (даже сам zip-уется при передаче). Что и как с ним делать на сервере - зависит от ваших задач и используемой серверной платформы.